# I don't understand the working principle of this metal detector circuit?

Tags: 555, multivibrator, metal

The circuit below is a metal detector circuit. The inductor serves as a "sensor" to detect metal. The tone of the speaker changes when a metal is detected. However, I don't know anything about how the circuit works internally. I can only do the circuit connection. Please can someone explain how how the internal circuit of the 555 time makes this possible? What mode is the IC operating? How does each passive component (resistors, inductors and capacitors) in the circuit functions? I need it urgently!

[image]

Comment: include the schematic diagram of the 555 in your circuit ... the answer may become apparent

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_loop It's probably operating as astable vibrator (an oscillator that oscillates and just keeps oscillating forever)

Comment: It is a group design project for my school work. My supervisor is a Doctor in electronic and electrical engineering. I presented the working circuit to him. He doesn't care that it works. He wants to know the full theory behind the circuit's operation. Please Monday is my next appointment with him. I have combed the internet and YouTube. But I just keep going round in circles. I don't understand anything. Thanks. Samson

Comment: jsotola. I will try my best to understand it if anyone gives an explanation.

Comment: Where did the working circuit *come from*?  Did you just mess around until it worked, or did you find the original schematic on the web?  **Where** did you find it on the web?  Do you have a link?  Is there an explanation there of how it works?

Comment: Have you tried simulating the circuit?  What did you find?  What do you expect to happen to the inductance of L1 in the presence of metal?   Why?

Comment: Read up on a general 555 timer tutorials one that shows the blocks inside the 555 timer and how it generally operates. Not one that only focuses on the various ways you can wire one up. This is my favorite one. THe original site has gone down but I found a copy of it online: http://www.engin.swarthmore.edu/~ejaoudi1/datasheets/555 and http://www.learningelectronics.net/VA3AVR/gadgets/555/555.html

Comment: I found it in a YouTube tutorial. The tutorial only explained how to connect the circuit.

Comment: https://youtu.be/FmmYviJ45bM

Comment: My geniuses and professors. I simulated the circuit

Comment: Thanks my geniuses. I appreciate the responses coming in.

Comment: @Samsonite You probably are supposed to be able to explain the full theory. Though in this case it isn't rocket science. The output of the 555 goes either high or low. You've got both the 1/3rd and 2/3rd thresholds tied together at a complex (I mean in a mathy way and not a difficult way) impedance divider node that's driven by the output that just goes high or low. When explaining the circuit, start by pointing out what happens when the series LC branch is disconnected. That should be easy enough to do. Then discuss what happens when you insert it back in place.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the fairly common 555 feedback astable circuit.
this uses the output pin instead of the discharge pin in the timing circuit.

[image]

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555-circuits-part-1.html

this circuit has been modified with a capacitor and the sense coil inductor in parallel with the timing resistor  this allows conductors and magnetic materials that come close to the sense coil to change its inductance and that change the allow less or more current to flow changing the frequency